# Embedded UITableView renders every cell at once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Structure: UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UITableView -> UITableViewCell

I just discovered that a UITableView embedded in a UITableViewCell will render all of its cells at once! That's including all non visible cells.

My tableView has hundreds of cells and cellForRowAtIndexPath, WillDisplay, and EndDisplaying are all being triggering at once.

Image-loads and my pagination algo are causing huge performance hits. Does anyone know how to prevent this behavior from happening?

---------- UPDATE: QUICK N DIRTY SOLUTION I DISCOVERED ------------

```
func fixCellBug(_ cell: SearchCard) {
    let top = max(tableView.contentOffset.y - cell.frame.minY - 30, 0) // 30 is slightly higher than the approximate minY of the tableView relative to its cell
    cell.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: top)
    cell.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: top)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        if let c = cell as? SearchCard {
            fixCellBug(c)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let c = cell as? SearchCard {
        fixCellBug(c)
    }
}
```

Also create an IBOutlet for the embedded tableView's height, set the height to `cell.tableViewHeight.constant = view.frame.height` in cellForRowAt in the master tableview.

A tableview will only render the cell if the cell's frame overlaps the tableview's frame. Thus we need to shrink the tableview's frame to at most the height of the screen. We also need to offset the top and contentOffset of the embedded tableView to FIX the tableView to the center of the screen when the user scrolls around.

Comment: Why do you have a table view inside the cells of another table view?

Comment: To produce a card view similar to iOS spotlight search results and Snapchat search. The second UITableView is embedded in the card. EX: https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/snapchat-search-features.png I've noticed that Snapchat search has poor performance as well as they might be suffering from the same issue.